# Magento 2 : Missing required argument

Tags: magento2

I am getting below error

Missing required argument `$additionalChecks` of `Vendor\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\MethodList`.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\QuoteGraphQl\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

/**
 * Methods List service class.
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class MethodList extends \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList
{
     /**
     * Configuration path for Payment from Applicable Countries (Afterpay)
     */
    const XML_PATH_PAYMENT_FROM_APPLICABLE_COUNTRIES = 'payment/afterpaypayovertime/allowspecific';

    /**
     * Configuration path for Payment from Specific Countries (Afterpay)
     */
    const XML_PATH_PAYMENT_FROM_SPECIFIC_COUNTRIES = 'payment/afterpaypayovertime/specificcountry';

    /**
     * Graphql area code
     */
    const AREA_CODE_GRAPHQL = 'graphql';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
     * @deprecated 100.1.0 Do not use this property in case of inheritance.
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory
     * @deprecated 100.2.0 Do not use this property in case of inheritance.
     */
    protected $methodSpecificationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private $paymentMethodList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private $paymentMethodInstanceFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $additionalChecks;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @var AppState
     */
    private $appState;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
     * @param Checks\SpecificationFactory  $specificationFactory
     * @param array                        $additionalChecks
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface         $config
     * @param AppState $appState
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory $specificationFactory,
        array $additionalChecks = [],
        ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->methodSpecificationFactory = $specificationFactory;
        $this->additionalChecks = $additionalChecks;
        $this->config           = $config;
        $this->appState         = $appState;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all available payment methods for the given quote.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface[]
     */
    public function getAvailableMethods(\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null)
    {
        $store = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;
        $availableMethods = [];
        $checkAfterpayAvailability = $quote ? $this->checkAfterpayAvailability($quote) : false;
        foreach ($this->getPaymentMethodList()->getActiveList($store) as $method) {
            if($checkAfterpayAvailability && $method->getCode() == "afterpaypayovertime"){
                continue;
            }
            $methodInstance = $this->getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()->create($method);
            if ($methodInstance->isAvailable($quote) && $this->_canUseMethod($methodInstance, $quote)) {
                $methodInstance->setInfoInstance($quote->getPayment());
                $availableMethods[] = $methodInstance;
            }
        }
        return $availableMethods;
    }

    /**
     * Check afterpay payment method allowed for country
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function checkAfterpayAvailability($quote) 
    {
        $allowedSpecific =  $this->config->getValue(self::XML_PATH_PAYMENT_FROM_APPLICABLE_COUNTRIES, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $allowedCountries =  explode(",", $this->config->getValue(self::XML_PATH_PAYMENT_FROM_SPECIFIC_COUNTRIES));
        $countryId = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
        if($allowedSpecific && $allowedCountries && $countryId && $this->appState->getAreaCode() == self::AREA_CODE_GRAPHQL) {
            $country_exist = array_intersect(array($countryId), $allowedCountries);
            if (!$country_exist){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check payment method model
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface $method
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _canUseMethod($method, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote)
    {
        return $this->methodSpecificationFactory->create(
            array_merge(
                [
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY,
                    AbstractMethod::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX,
                ],
                $this->additionalChecks
            )
        )->isApplicable(
            $method,
            $quote
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method list.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodList()
    {
        if ($this->paymentMethodList === null) {
            $this->paymentMethodList = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface::class
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethodList;
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method instance factory.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()
    {
        if ($this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory === null) {
            $this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **after, before plugin methods**.we can change the after changes parameter, return value of the original getAvailableMethods()

if you want to **full changes return of this function then use around methods aroundGetAvailableMethods().**

```
<?php


namespace StackExchanges\OnlyMagento\Plugin\Magento\Payment\Model;


class MethodListPlugin {
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data
     * @deprecated 100.1.3 Do not use this property in case of inheritance.
     */
    protected $paymentHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory
     * @deprecated 100.2.0 Do not use this property in case of inheritance.
     */
    protected $methodSpecificationFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private $paymentMethodList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private $paymentMethodInstanceFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper
     * @param Checks\SpecificationFactory $specificationFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Checks\SpecificationFactory $specificationFactory
    ) {
        $this->paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;
        $this->methodSpecificationFactory = $specificationFactory;
    }
    public function aroundGetAvailableMethods(
        \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,    
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote = null
    )
    {
        /*
         * if want to origina function then use 
         *  return $proceed($quote);
         */

        $store = $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null;
        $availableMethods = [];

        foreach ($this->getPaymentMethodList()->getActiveList($store) as $method) {
            $methodInstance = $this->getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()->create($method);
            if ($methodInstance->isAvailable($quote) && $this->_canUseMethod($methodInstance, $quote)) {
                $methodInstance->setInfoInstance($quote->getPayment());
                $availableMethods[] = $methodInstance;
            }
        }
        /**
         * return of $availableMethod mean you have override 
         *  original function fully
         * 
         */
        return $availableMethods;        
    }
   /**
     * Check payment method model
     *
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Model\MethodInterface $method
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _canUseMethod($method, \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $quote)
    {
        return $this->methodSpecificationFactory->create(
            [
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT,
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY,
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY,
                AbstractMethod::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX,
            ]
        )->isApplicable(
            $method,
            $quote
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method list.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodList()
    {
        if ($this->paymentMethodList === null) {
            $this->paymentMethodList = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Payment\Api\PaymentMethodListInterface::class
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethodList;
    }

    /**
     * Get payment method instance factory.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory
     */
    private function getPaymentMethodInstanceFactory()
    {
        if ($this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory === null) {
            $this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\InstanceFactory::class
            );
        }
        return $this->paymentMethodInstanceFactory;
    }    
}
```